# regex match all xml tags that contain a certain attribute value

Tags: regex, xml, perl

I have an xml file where I want to match all xml tags that contain an attribute matching a certain string in Perl.

Sample XML:

```
<item attr="Car" />
<item attr="Apple_And_Pears.htm#123" />
<item attr="Paper" />
<item attr="Orange_And_Peach.htm#213" />
```

I want a regex that grabs all nodes that has an attribute that contains ".htm"

```
<item attr="Orange_And_Peach.htm#213" />
<item attr="Apple_And_Pears.htm#123" />
```

With the following regex, I'm matching with all tags rather than only tags with .htm attribute:

```
<item.*?attr="[^>]*>
```

Is there some sort of positive lookahead until a certain character?

Thanks

Comment: Re "_Is there some sort of ..._" -- there are proper XML parsers, best [XML::LibXML](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML) and [XML::Twig](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig).  There are also other (larger) frameworks that contain this as well. Just don't do it by hand, with regex, since there's no end of trouble to that (unless it's really _really_ simple, only one thing, just this once ... but which it normally isn't, even if it may start out that way).

Comment: For instance, Grinnz's answer is one good way to go

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The appropriate Perl solution is not regex. With [Mojo::DOM](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::DOM) (one of many options):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Mojo::DOM;
use File::Slurper 'read_text';

my $xml = read_text 'test.xml';
my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new->xml(1)->parse($xml);
my $tags = $dom->find('item[attr*=".htm"]');
print "$_\n" for @$tags;
```

Comment: Plus one for ***not*** obliging the request to parse XML via regex but rather showing OP a better way.

Answer (score 1):

As Grinnz suggested you should use an approriate xml-parser (check out this interesting post on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751105/why-its-not-possible-to-use-regex-to-parse-html-xml-a-formal-explanation-in-la) explaining why), but since you asked for it here's a simple regex you could use with a positive lookahead:

`<item.*?attr=".*(?=\.htm).*`

If you want to match tags with only one ".htm" in it, you can use both a negative and positive lookaround:

`^(?:(?!\.htm).)*\.htm(?!.*\.htm).*$`

Comment: I think it's important to note these regexes will be incredibly inefficient and very difficult to restrict to a single "tag". Non-greedy quantifiers are often assumed to be something smarter than they actually are, which is just "as few characters as will lead to a successful overall match starting from the point we have already reached".

Comment: (-1)   Aside from inefficiencies, **regex is also incredibly brittle for parsing XML.** When someone asks how to shoot themselves in the foot, the right thing to do is not to help them aim.  The right thing is to show them [a better way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54447547/290085).

Comment: @kjhughes Excuse me, but I don't really understand your comment and I don't see the need for a downvote. I never adviced him/her to use this regex-based solution, since I actually wrote to prefer Grinnz' solution in the first sentence?! I added the regex solution just in case he/she wanted to know how such a regex with lookarounds would look like and it might be useful in another situation where the use of regex is valid ...